# Exclamation point in top right of windows - over the close button

Tags: java, swing, security, java-web-start

When I open some Java applications, especially examples launched from Java Web Start, I will often see an exclamation mark next to/covering the close button, depending on the window size. It is a bit worrying actually.

What does it mean, and what is its function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the app. is sand-boxed.
The function of it is to inform the user that an app. is running that is sand-boxed.

[image: Window w. exclamation mark]

See [Exploring Security Warning Functionality](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/SecurityWarning/AppletWarning.html) for more details.

It is supposed to be a bit worrying, actually.  Don't go typing your bank account details into one of those floating windows that looks 'something like' your bank log-on.  ;)

Comment: +1, I am exploring `JNLP` now and face the same problem. Is it possible to disable that triangle?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Digitally sign the app. and declare `j2ee-application-client-permissions` or `all-permissions`.  You really should ask that on a separate question.